# How to call async methods from within a Prism event aggregator subscriber?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, prism

Quick question - how do I call async methods from within a Prism event aggregator subscriber action? E.g.

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<SomeMessage>>()
   .Subscribe((msg) => {
                       DoSomething();
                       await DoSomethingAsync();
                       DoSomethingElse();
                    });
```

Comment: You can stick `async` in front of your lambda e.g. `async (msg) => { ... }`, but  `Subscribe` won't wait for it to complete.

Comment: @CharlesMager Aah, as simple as that! Many thanks.

Comment: @CharlesMager this will create async void which is not recommended solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just making @Charles Mager a answer

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<SomeMessage>>()
   .Subscribe(async(msg) => {
                       DoSomething();
                       await DoSomethingAsync();
                       DoSomethingElse();
                    });
```

Comment: Will it create `async void` method from this lambda method ? Isn't it not recommended ?

Comment: No, this is no good solution. It works but it is a "fire and forget" style. No exceptions are caught.

Answer (score 3):

With current Prism implementation, it is not possible [see here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/832).

But I have found an alternate implementation of Prism's EventAggregator, which allows `async` subscriptions. See [here](https://github.com/fluendo/VAS/tree/master/VAS.Core/Prism).

This new event async aggregator overloads can be used in the same way as the original one:

Subscription to event is exactly the same with another overload:

```
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<<TfsHookEvent<WorkItemUpdatedPayload>>().Subscribe(WorkItem_Updated);
```

Event handler:

```
    private async Task WorkItem_Updated(WorkItemUpdatedPayload obj)
    {
        await CheckAsync();
    }
```

Comment: How do we include those classes? There does not seem to be a Nuget package, and simply pasting the necessary files into my own solution results in conflicting classes

Comment: I downloaded Prism sources and replaced files from the source above. Not an ideal solution. There is no NuGet package.